# SVG animation pattern - Traffic light

Tags: html, svg

I want to animate a repeating traffic light just like in real life. I am changing the opacity from dark to brighter to display which light is on. Which works but it doesn't repeat.

**Pattern I want**
Redlight for 6 seconds...turn off
then begin Yellowlight for 3 seconds...turn off
then begin Greenlight for 6 seconds...turn off 
Then back to Yellowlight for 3 seconds...turn off
Then back to Redlight for 6 seconds ...turn off
and the pattern keeps repeating.

**Pattern I have**
Redlight begin at 0s for 2 seconds ...then turn off
Yellowlight begin at 2s for 2 seconds...then turn off 
Greenlight begin at 4s for 2 seconds...then turn off 
They all stay off (no repeat)

The SVG code (for the pattern I have):

```
<svg>

<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="400" y2="100" style="stroke: green; stroke-width:50" />
<line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="600" style="stroke: green; stroke-width:50" />
<rect x="300" y="600" height="100" width="200" fill="green"></rect>

<rect id="stoplight" x="30" y="0" height="308" width="100"></rect>
<rect id="redlight" x="55" y="25" height="60" width="50"></rect>
<animate xlink:href="#redlight" id="redlight" attributeName="opacity" from=".3" to="1" dur="2s" begin="0s"/>
<rect id="yellowlight" x="55" y="125" height="60" width="50"></rect> 
<animate xlink:href="#yellowlight" id="yellowlight" attributeName="opacity" from=".3" to="1" dur="2s" begin="2s"/>
<rect id="greenlight" x="55" y="225" height="60" width="50"></rect>
<animate xlink:href="#greenlight" id="greenlight" attributeName="opacity" from=".3" to="1" dur="2s" begin= "4s" />
</svg>
```

We just started learning SVG so I'm just a beginner.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxkecjL9/)

**Update** Edited the code with repeating lights working. Issues with the pattern, the yellow light transitions back to red light.
**Updated:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48Lnvko8/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You've multiple elements with the same id which is invalid. After fixing that you can target the animation end correctly e.g.

```
<rect id="stoplight" x="30" y="0" height="308" width="100"></rect>
<rect id="redlight" x="55" y="25" height="60" width="50"></rect>
<animate xlink:href="#redlight" id="redlight2" attributeName="opacity" from=".3" to="1" dur="2s" begin="0s;greenlight2.end"/>
<rect id="yellowlight" x="55" y="125" height="60" width="50"></rect> 
<animate xlink:href="#yellowlight" id="yellowlight2" attributeName="opacity" from=".3" to="1" dur="2s" begin="2s"/>
<rect id="greenlight" x="55" y="225" height="60" width="50"></rect>
<animate xlink:href="#greenlight" id="greenlight2" attributeName="opacity" from=".3" to="1" dur="2s" begin="4s" />
```

Comment: Oooo derr on my part. But awesome, I did not know you could do multiple begin points. I'm glad I asked. Thank you.

Comment: Now my issue is the yellow light, I get it to turn back on after green and then red and green both turn on. How would I fix that? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48Lnvko8/3/).

Comment: Please don't morph the question, it makes my answer seem like nonsense. Ask another question instead.

Comment: any idea on getting the yellow light transition to go from green to yellow to red?