# How do i make a button that will keep changing the light each time i press it for a traffic light?

Tags: javascript, svg

i need my code to keep changing the lights. each time i press the button i want the traffic light to display red then red and yellow together then green only and i want this process to repeat each time i press the button. i need help for this. so far i have got this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Traffic Light</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Traffic Light</h1>
<p>Click the button for light to change.</p>

<div

style="width:100.5px;height:320px;border:3px solid #000;">

<button onclick=circle2.style.fill="yellow";><Change Lights
<button onclick=circle1.style.fill="transparent";><Change Lights
<button onclick=circle2.style.fill="transparent";><Change Lights
<button onclick=circle3.style.fill="green";>Change Lights
</button>

<svg id="svg1" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle1" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: red; stroke: black;      stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>

<svg id="svg2" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle2" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>

<svg id="svg3"style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle3" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>

</script>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

can you please help me find the solution for my work 
thank you.

Comment: You forgot to show your JavaScript, although you *did* include the closing `</script>` tag for some reason. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? As for "*[helping you] find the solution for [your] work*" - no: *you* come up with the solution, and then, when - or if - you have problems you can come back and ask us about those specific problems, having shown your work and explained the problem, the behaviour and the expected behaviour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634993/svg-animation-pattern-traffic-light

Comment: Just create single svg and change circle fill on click.

Comment: @DavidThomas Relax basically i know how to make my code work but my only problem is that the yellow circle is not going transparent when button is clicked. can you please help me

Comment: Telling me, or us in general, that "*basically you know*" isn't showing us the code that you've attempted, and that's what we really need to see; without seeing your JavaScript it seems that you're asking us to provide a full solution, rather than helping you to correct the problems in your current solution. I'm genuinely sorry if this feels in any way hostile, but writing your code for you isn't what SO is here for. *Helping* you, however, *is* what we're here for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<p>Click the button for light to change.</p>

<div

style="width:100.5px;height:420px;border:3px solid #000;">

<button onclick='circle2.style.fill="yellow"'>Change Lights</button>
<button onclick='circle1.style.fill="transparent"'>Change Lights</button>
<button onclick='circle2.style.fill="transparent"'>Change Lights</button>
<button onclick='circle3.style.fill="green"'>Change Lights</button>

<svg id="svg1" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle1" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: red; stroke: black;      stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>

<svg id="svg2" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle2" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>

<svg id="svg3"style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle3" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but i need this process to continue and i need to do this with one button only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];
var index = 0;
document.getElementById('traffic').onclick = function() {
  index++;
  if (index == colors.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  circle.style.fill = colors[index];
};
```

```html
<button id="traffic">Change Lights</button>

<svg id="svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" style="fill: red; stroke: black;      stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: this code is really good but i need three circles doing that thank you for helping.